# SQL Server Management Studio highlights a word that does not appear to be a reserved word

Tags: sql-server

I don't like to name objects with reserved word (i.e. `Set`) for all the obvious reasons.

So when SSMS highlights a word in blue, I rethink my naming of the object.

Every once and a while I see a word highlighted that does not appear to be in the list of [reserved words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). In this case the word `pool`.

Does SSMS use a more strict convention for highlighting reserved words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSMS uses color syntax highlighting for keywords that are not necessarily reserved keywords, but are keywords in the context of certain statements.  For example `POOL` is a keyword as in `CREATE RESOURCE POOL`.  SSMS will show the word in a different color even when not in the context of a `CREATE` or `ALTER` resource pool.